# method that return only odd numbers (int) in java

Tags: java, random, do-while

So, I am trying to create a method that return random numbers within range (1-43), but only odd numbers. I used do-while statement, but the program keeps returning many kinds of numbers - even and odd alike. can you please tell me whats wrong with it, so it will return only the requested type of number (depended on: % = 0/1)?

```
public static String generateRandomOddNumbersWithinRange(){

    int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 43 + 1);

    do {
        return Integer.toString(randomNum);

    } while (randomNum % 2 == 1);
}
```

Comment: Your `do-while` loop is ignored completely since you return from it as the first thing.

Comment: genreate beetwen 0-21 and multiply by 2 then add 1

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for the answer. but what do you mean: "as the first thing"?

Comment: I mean you enter the loop, then you return. Returning from inside the loop does not allow the loop to continue.

Answer (score 8):

You're returning unconditionally. Instead, you should loop until a number meets the criteria, and only then return it:

```
public static String generateRandomOddNumbersWithinRange(){

    int randomNum = 0;
    do {
        randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 43 + 1);
    } while (randomNum % 2 == 0);
    return Integer.toString(randomNum);
}
```

Alternatively, a more robust solution could be to randomize a number between 0 and 21, and then double it and add one:

```
public static String generateRandomOddNumbersWithinRange(){
    return Integer.toString(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 21 + 1) * 2 + 1);
}
```

Comment: you forgot to multiply in the second solution

Comment: @jonatjano thanks for noticing - I described this in the text, but forgot to do so in the code. Edited and fixed.

Comment: @Mureinik in the second solution, you need to change the method type to "int" insted of "String"

Comment: @RonGal120 or convert it to string. I was following your signature and returning a `String` in both (although I think just returning an `int` would indeed be more elegant).

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep generating random numbers until you get an odd one, so `int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 43 + 1)` should be inside the loop. Also, don't return immediately! First, check if the number is indeed an odd one or not, and return only if this is true. With this, you can even return from outside of the loop. Something like:

```
int randomNum = 0;
do {
  randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 43 + 1);
} while (randomNum % 2 == 1);

return Integer.toString(randomNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You return the value before checking for odd or even

```
public static String generateRandomOddNumbersWithinRange(){    
    int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 43 + 1);

    do {
        return Integer.toString(randomNum); // return the value

    } while (randomNum % 2 == 1); // check for odd or even
}
```

Put the return statement after the check. Something like this:

```
public static String generateRandomOddNumbersWithinRange(){
    int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 43 + 1);
    while ( randomNum % 2 == 0 ) {
      // if not odd, overwrite value
      randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 43 + 1);
    }
    return Integer.toString(randomNum);
}
```

Comment: According to my oppinion this do-while solution is not so effective.

Comment: @zappee the do-while is code from the original post. I've seen other suggestions where a simple - 1 is applied to the result if the result is even, but solutions like this ignore the boundaries set for the valid results, so they're not all that effective either

Answer (score 0):

Your code only runs once and immediately returns a value, no matter what it is. Rather do this:

```
public static String generateRandomOddNumbersWithinRange(){

    int randomNum;

    do {
        randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 43 + 1);

    } while (randomNum % 2 == 0);

    return Integer.toString(randomNum);
}
```

This keeps assigning a random number to randomNum when randomNum / 2 has anything left over.

Comment: `random % 2 < 0` with numbers between 1 and 43 means if a number mod 2 is negative which will never work.

Comment: Sorry! Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use do-while. This is the method what you need to use:

```
public static int generateRandomOddNumbersWithinRange(final int min, final int max) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    if ((randomNumber & 1) != 0) {
        return randomNumber;
    }

    return randomNumber - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just double it and add 1?

```
public static int generateRandomOddNumber(int max) {
    int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, ((max - 1) / 2) + 1);
    return (randomNum * 2) + 1;
}

public void test() {
    Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        int r = generateRandomOddNumber(43);
        // How many of that value have we had so far?
        int count = counts.containsKey(r) ? counts.get(r) : 0;
        // We've just had another one.
        counts.put(r, count + 1);
    }
    // Pull the results out into a list.
    List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> countsList = new ArrayList<>(counts.entrySet());
    // Sort them.
    Collections.sort(countsList, Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getKey));
    System.out.println(countsList);
}
```

This prints:

> [1=460, 3=463, 5=445, 7=441, 9=407, 11=467, 13=438, 15=483, 17=454, 19=463, 21=501, 23=444, 25=455, 27=419, 29=425, 31=460, 33=492, 35=449, 37=440, 39=495, 41=463, 43=436]

Which looks like it is doing it right.

Comment: your code looks impresive, but too complicated for my needs. I don't need HashMap or List, just a simple int

Comment: @RonGal120 - That is only the testing to make sure of an even spread from `1` to `43` - look at  my `generateRandomOddNumber(int max)`! **Much** simpler than yours.